# Why realizability topos instead of category of assemblies?

Tags: topos-theory, constructive-mathematics, categorical-logic

A realizability topos is the exact completion of a category of assemblies.
If I understood correctly, the major achievement of the completion is having (1) subobject
classifier and (2) finite colimits, including coequalizers of equivalence relations.

However, a category of assemblies seems rich enough to model (certain) constructive dependent type theories with a straightforward interpretation: terms to computable functions and types to data types (assemblies).

I was wondering then what the main motivation and advantage of inventing this completion, having subobject classifier and quotients, and working with realizability topos instead of a category of assemblies are.

Will there be some illuminating examples that can only be done in a realizability topos but not in a category of assemblies?

Comment: I don't know about you, but I find having quotients and a subobject classifier to be very convenient for doing mathematics.